# Meromorphic function with simple pole at prescribed points

Tags: complex-analysis

The problem is :

Construct a meromorphic function on $\mathbb C$ with simple poles at $\log(n)$, $n \geq 1$, and the principal part being $\dfrac{1}{z-\log(n)}$.

What I am thinking is: to use the convergence of $$\sum_{n \in \mathbb N}\frac{1}{n^{p}(z-\log(n))}$$ for any $p > 1$. But till now cannot provide a complete solution to this problem.

Comment: That would give you the wrong principal parts, namely $$\frac{1}{n^p(z-\log n)}$$ instead of $\frac{1}{z-\log n}$.

Comment: But $\sum_{n \in \mathbb N}\frac{1}{z-log(n)}$ is NOT convergent.. So..what to do??

Comment: The standard solution in the books is to subtract a Taylor polynomial of $\frac{1}{z-\log n}$ of sufficiently high order to obtain convergence. Here, with your start, you can use a neat trick to get something in some sense simpler. Let $$g(z) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}} \frac{1}{n^p(z-\log n)}.$$ Then try to find an entire $h$ such that $h(z)\cdot g(z)$ has the right principal parts. You need $h(\log n) = n^p$.

Comment: I did not get the last two lines. What is our target, in this way?? Also, if you can, please provide that standard solution.

Comment: You should look up Mittag-Leffler theorem.  In particular, you may find proof of this via the $\overline{\partial}$ method to be compelling and general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard construction of a meromorphic function with simple poles in $\{a_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and principal part $\frac{1}{z-a_n}$ in the pole $a_n$, where the $a_n$ are distinct and $\lim_{n\to\infty} \lvert a_n \rvert = \infty$ is to consider a series

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{z-a_n} - P_n(z)\right),$$

where $P_n$ as a Taylor polynomial of $\frac{1}{z-a_n}$ (for $a_n \neq 0$, for $a_n = 0$ one takes $P_n = 0$) of sufficiently high order to have convergence. Since, for $\lvert z\rvert < \lvert a_n\rvert$, we have

$$\frac{1}{z-a_n} = -\frac{1}{a_n} \frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{a_n}} = - \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{a_n^{k+1}},$$

one considers

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{z-a_n} + \sum_{k=0}^{K_n} \frac{z^k}{a_n^{k+1}}\right)$$

where the $K_n$ are chosen so that the series converges compactly. For every sequence $a_n \to \infty$, one can choose the $K_n$ to achieve that. For $n$ so large that $\lvert a_n\rvert \geqslant 2\lvert z\rvert$, we can estimate

$$\left\lvert \frac{1}{z-a_n} + \sum_{k=0}^{K_n} \frac{z^k}{a_n^{k+1}}\right\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{\lvert a_n\rvert} \sum_{k=K_n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} = \frac{1}{2^{K_n}\lvert a_n\rvert},$$

so the choice $K_n = n$ always works.

It is nice if one can take $K_n$ the same for all $n$, but for $a_n = \log n$ [throwing out $n = 0$], that isn't possible.

Here, your ansatz gives a solution that is in some sense simpler. Starting with

$$g(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p(z-\log n)},$$

which is - for any $p > 1$ - an entire meromorphic function with simple poles in each $\log n$ and nowhere else, the only problem is that $g$ has the wrong principal parts, namely $$\frac{1}{n^p(z-\log n)}.$$ Now, if $h$ is an arbitrary entire function, then we obtain the Laurent expansion

$$h(z)g(z) = \left(h(\log n) + (z-\log n)h_1(z)\right)\left(\frac{1}{n^p(z-\log n)} + g_1(z)\right) = \frac{h(\log n)}{n^p(z-\log n)} + p(z),$$

where $h_1,\,g_1$ and $p$ are holomorphic in $\log n$, so the principal part of $h\cdot g$ in $\log n$ is

$$\frac{h(\log n)}{n^p(z-\log n)}.$$

If you can find a $h$ with $h(\log n) = n^p$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$, you have a solution for your problem.

Comment: So...$h(z)=e^{pz}$ is clearly an entire funtion, which has the desired property & we are done!... is it correct??

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The expected answer is, I'm pretty sure, the standard way, however.

Comment: "It is nice if one can take $K_{n}$ the same for all $n$ ... " .. Did you mean constant $K_{n}$ ??

Comment: Yes, $K_n = m$ for all $n$. But that is only possible if $\lvert a_n\rvert$ grows fast enough.

Comment: Yuup..the standard procedure is more general...Thank you.. Daniel Fischer.

Comment: Why in the case of $log n$ the choice of $K_n=n$ is not possible? The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^nlog n}$ is convergent.