# Meromorphic function with poles only at natural numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

By the Mittag-Leffler theorem, there exists a meromorphic function $f$ such that it has poles at all natural numbers and nowhere else. The problem is to directly construct such a function with residues at $n \in \mathbb{N}$ equal to the same number $n$. If $f$ is such a function, then $$f - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(1/(z-n) + 1/n)$$ should be holomorphic, however, taking just $f=0$ doesn't quite work, because the harmonic series diverges. Can someone help me finish this construction?

Comment: Your sum diverges, $\sum_{n \geq 1} (n/(z - n) + 1 + z/n)$ is convergent though. Or you can use the fact that $\operatorname {Res}_{z = -n} \psi(z) = -1$ for $n \in \mathbb N^0$.

Comment: Think of $\Gamma(-z+1)$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a meromorphic function with poles exactly at the positive integers, and principal parts
$$
 \frac{n}{z-n}
$$
at $z=n$. A common approach is to construct a series of the form
$$
 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{z-n} - T_n(z)
$$
where $T_n(z)$ is a Taylor polynomial of $\frac{n}{z-n}$ at $z=0$ of sufficiently high degree to make the series converge (uniformly on compact sets). Since
$$
 \frac{n}{z-n} = -1 - \frac{z}{n} - \frac{z^2}{n^2} -\ldots
$$
we can choose
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{z-n} +1 + \frac zn = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^2}{(z-n)n} \, .
$$
The series is convergent because the denominator grows quadratic in $n$.

Comment: Why does this converge uniformly on compact sets? Should not $|\frac{n}{z-n} - T_n(z)| < 2^{-n}$ for $|z|<\frac{n}{2}$.

Comment: @whiterock: For $|z| < R < n$ is $\left|\frac{z^2}{(z-n)n} \right| \le \frac{R^2}{(n-R)n}$, so that the series converges uniformly in $|z| < R$ by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test.

Comment: Also see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990450)

Comment: This is related to the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: The digamma function has simple poles at $0, -1, -2, \ldots$ with residue $1$, so I do not see a direct connection.